Unity field of "random between two constants"
In Unity particle system, many parameters can be a "random between two constants". In custom MonoBehavior, is there a similar built-in type that is shown as a range (two floats) in Inspector and is a determined random value when read in the class methods?
I know it can be done with two float members "min" and "max", or write a custom class to achieve this purpose. But I wonder whether such a built-in type already exist. Don't want to unnecessarily reinvent the wheel.

I think Random Between Two Constants was from the old Shuriken particle system.  The replacement functionality is  ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve.  I usually just use a Vector2 and Random.Range.

you can use this free asset https://github.com/dbrizov/NaughtyAttributes?tab=readme-ov-file#minmaxslider and you can use it by Random.Range(minMaxSlider.x,minMaxSlider.y);

Thanks @PrajwalNagpure for pointing out the lib. It's super handy!

Naughty Attributes indeed brings a lot of fancy drawers and features - but yeah there is nothing built-in for this
